# Converting the projection of lat and long columns of a CSV file

Tags: r, coordinates, qgis

I have a CSV file with two lat and long columns. The coordinates are in NAD83/BC Albers projection;epsg=3005. Here you can see a small part of my CSV file.

[image]

I need to add two new coordinate columns to my table and convert the coordinates to WGS84 with epsg= 4326. I have done any technique possible in QGIS and r. The new columns are added, but they are the same coordinates, and coordinate values do not change.
How can I perform this conversion?

Comment: please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# define data
df <- tribble(
       ~x,       ~y,
  1266750, 488433.9,
  1194789,   388522,
  1114525, 399475.2,
  1249751, 478679.9
)

# make spatially aware and reproject
df |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 3005) |> 
  st_transform(crs = 4326)
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -124.45 ymin: 48.48 xmax: -122.33 ymax: 49.35
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>          geometry
#> *     <POINT [°]>
#> 1 (-122.33 49.35)
#> 2 (-123.37 48.48)
#> 3  (-124.45 48.6)
#> 4 (-122.57 49.27)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>